# Query on Uniform random variable MAX & MIN

Tags: probability

Llet $U$ and $V$ be independent, continuous uniform random variables on the interval $\left[1,5\right]$. Find $$\Pr\left(\min\left(U,V\right)<2 \mid \max\left(U,V\right)>2\right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \Pr\left( \min(U,V)<2 \mid \max(U,V)>2\right) &=& \frac{\Pr\left( \min(U,V)<2, \max(U,V)>2\right)}{\Pr\left(\max(U,V)>2\right)} \cr &=& \frac{2 \Pr\left( \min(U,V)<2, \max(U,V)>2, U < V\right)}{2 \Pr\left(\max(U,V)>2, U < V\right)} \cr &=& \frac{ \Pr\left( U<2, V>2\right)}{\Pr\left(U < V, V > 2\right)}
\end{eqnarray} 
$$
where the second equality follows from the following identity, valid for any exchangeable event $\mathcal{E}$:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
  \Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(U,V\right)\right) &=& \Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(U,V\right), U < V\right) +\Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(U,V\right), U > V\right) \cr &=& \Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(U,V\right), U < V\right) + \underbrace{\Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(V,U\right), V > U\right)}_{\mathrm{renamed }\phantom{m} U \leftrightarrow V} \cr  &=& 
 2 \cdot \Pr\left(\mathcal{E}\left(U,V\right), U < V\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Continuing:
$$
\frac{ \Pr\left( U<2, V>2\right)}{\Pr\left(U < V, V > 2\right)} = \frac{ \Pr\left( U<2\right) \cdot \Pr\left( V > 2\right)}{\mathbb{E}\left(\Pr\left(U < V, V > 2 \mid V \right)\right)} = \frac{\frac{2-1}{5-1} \cdot \frac{5-2}{5-1} }{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{V-1}{5-1}, V > 2\right)} = \frac{\frac{3}{16}}{\frac{1}{16} \int_{2}^{5} \left(v-1\right) \mathrm{d}v} 
$$
Hence
$$
  \Pr\left( \min(U,V)<2 \mid \max(U,V)>2\right) = \frac{2}{5}
$$

Confirm in *Mathematica*:

```
In[1]:= Probability[ Min[u, v]<2 ~Conditioned~ Max[u,v]>2,
      {u ~Distributed~ UniformDistribution[{1,5}],
       v ~Distributed~ UniformDistribution[{1,5}] }]

Out[1]= 2/5
```

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for $\mathsf P(\min (U,V)<2\mid \max(U,V)>2)$ when $U,V~\mathop{\sim}\limits^{iid}~\mathcal U[1;5]$.

Since the random variables are uniformly and independently distributed, we can solve this graphically by just comparing areas corresponding to the events.

We can divide the $[2;5]^2$ square into four rectangles and measure their areas$$\lvert U<\cap V<2\rvert = 1,\\ \lvert U<2\cap V>2\rvert = \lvert U>2\cap V<2\rvert = 3 \\ \lvert U>2\cap V>2\rvert = 9$$

Then it's simply a matter of applying Bayes' rule.
$$\mathsf P(U<2\cup V<2\mid U>2\cup V>2) = \dfrac{3+3}{3+3+9} = \dfrac{2}{5}$$